# Removing dynamically generated elements, when clicking on an element within itself in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I remove a dynamically generated block of elements when clicking the button inside of it?

```
function controlContent(target, trigger) {
    //this will add a new div to target which is an existing html element
    $(trigger).on("click", () => {
        $(target).append(`
            <div class="dynamic-container">
                <button class="remove-btn">Remove the div I am inside</button>
            </div>
        `)
    }

    //this should remove the div that was added when I click the remove button
    $(target).on("click", ".remove-btn", () => {
        $(this).closest(".dynamic-container").remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jQuery, but it does seem to have a `parent()` selector - would that work?

Comment: Don't use an arrow function, you're getting the wrong `this`.

Comment: You should just delegate the removal handler once, from a static container element, not every time you add an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FIRST:** you should use `$(document).on("click", target, function(){...}` for dynamically generated elements

**SECOND:** As simple as `parent()`

```
$(document).on("click", target, function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
$(".button1").on("click", function(){
$(".generatedbuttons").append('<div class="green"><button class="button2">Click me to remove me and my parent</button></div>');
});
$(document).on("click", ".button2", function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.button1 {
display:block;
float: left;
}
.green {
padding: 10px;
background-color: green;
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button1">Click me to generate buttons</button>

<div class="generatedbuttons">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

use normal function and also use dynamic click listener so you don't need to create a new event lister every time.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function(){
    $(this).closest(".dynamic-container").remove();
})
```